# Change color of typed text in Remmina

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, remmina

In my Remmina SSh sessions, the username, machine name, path as well as the input and output text in the console all have the same color as seen in the picture.

[image: Same colors for all the text]

When I open the preferences, I can only set up some information such as a foreground, a background or a cursor color:

[image: Remmina preferences]

How can I set up that the input and output text is different then the color of the machine name, username and path like in my local terminal?

[image: Local terminal]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not at Remmina, it is actually because of the server terminal display. You have to check for the `$TERM` at the terminal for color setup.

I think, 99% in your case, the `echo $TERM` is not `xterm-color` or any terminal with `256-colors`. Therefore, the `~/.bashrc` can't trigger the color modification. You can check this by inspecting the `~/.bashrc` in the server at this line.

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Then, you can add your terminal type (such as `xterm`) by`xterm|xterm-color|*-256color`. Or you can make it accept you no matter what by removing the `case` condition

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
color_prompt=yes
```

Then save it and reload the `~/.bashrc`.

Before modification: [image: before]

After modification: [image: after]

Answer (score 0):

You should run commands on startup. for Automate these commands:

1. Edit connection.
2. In the `Basic` tab fill:

```
    TERM=xterm-256color; source ~/.bashrc
```

3. press `Save and Connect` button.